# what's wrong with this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The after morning (1)/ she woke to the first ray of (2)/ light through the window. (3)/No Error (4).

What is the error in this sentence. please explain.

Comment: What do you think yourself?

Comment: May be  it should be  the morning after ,but i m not sure

Comment: There's an error in phrase number one but I'll not tell you.

Comment: Presumably the `(1)` etc. are where you (or whoever created this question) thinks there are problems... are the slashes `/` just part of marking where the problems are, or are they significant in their own right? (E.g. they're sometimes used when quoting poetry to show where line-breaks occur). Also, you have two sentences; is the second ("_No Error_") intended to be related/connected to the first, or is it entirely separate?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is wrong.  "After" should not precede "morning" in this context.

The corrected sentence should read

> The morning after, she woke to the first ray of light through the window.

or more commonly,

> The following morning, she woke to the first ray of light through the window.

Both sentences occur after a comment about the night before.  Note that the phrase "the morning after" may imply that she had sex the night before.  "The morning after pill" is a frequently referenced form of contraception, so "the morning after" has become something of an idiom used in this context.

Comment: "The next morning" is another possibility.